# init.d script is not executed

Tags: bash, init.d, sh

I have an /etc/init.d script that starts my webserver.
I made it executable and added it (`update-rc.d webserver defaults`).
When I execute the script from the command line it works fine (`./webserver`).

But after rebooting my system my webserver is not running.

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin

cd ~/projects/webserver
./.build/debug/webserver &
exit 0
```

Is the user directory a problem (I am logged in as root)?

Comment: Kindly post the output **ls -lht /etc/init.d/webserver**

Comment: Tilde expansion is done in reference to the current user. I don't see how it can work if the script runs before login (loading the env). Use the full path instead of `~`

Comment: You never mentioned whether the links to it, `/etc/rc.d/*/S*webserver` exist. This is important because the scripts in /etc/init.d are not directly executed at boot/shutdown.  The S* scripts are run at boot and the K* scripts at shutdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of tilde expansion you want is performed in reference to the current user of the shell. For example, when you log in as root `~` is `/root`. If the script runs before you log in, then `~` cannot be expanded to the directory you want.

Use the full path to the file in your script.

For future reference, [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-tilde-expansion/) are some useful examples of using tilde expansion in scripts

Answer (score 3):

Well there is a problem in your script. When you write script better use aboslute path instead of **tilde(~)**. Thats could be the culprit that made the script unusable. If you want to change dir, give the full path like /home/scripts/projects/ instead of *~/projects* .It makes a lot more difference.

To achieve your goal, there are several ways. Being a Senior Systems Engineer , I use different methodology to achieve such things which depends on the situations. Well here I list some of many ways.

1) Basic way what you tied and not succeeded .

```
sudo su
chmod a+x /etc/init.d/webserver
update-rc.d webserver defaults
```

2) Add a cron job at reboots.

```
sudo su
crontab -e
@reboot /home/path/to/script.sh
```

3) Add  your commands to rc.local file before the last line **exit 0**.

```
sudo su
nano /etc/rc.local
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
cd /absolute/path/projects/webserver
./.build/debug/webserver &
```

Comment: The spelling of the name of that character is tilde, not tilde.

Comment: Its a typing mistake. Thanks for mentioning. I 've edited it.